# InvalidInput on azure REST entity group transaction on table storage

Tags: azure, rest, dart, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I cannot figure out what to do here. According to the docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions

I send a post request to

```dart
var url = 'https://$myaccount.table.core.windows.net/\$batch?sv=($sasToken)'
```

headers:

```dart
   var headers = {
      "x-ms-date": "2021-12-06 22:12:15.862319Z"
      "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8"
      "x-ms-version": "2020-10-02"
      "content-type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_8360b73e-53ce-4ab8-8de8-3894086bd694"
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
      "DataServiceVersion": "3.0"
      "MaxDataServiceVersion": "3.0;NetFx"
   }
```

body:

```dart
var body = '''
--batch_8360b73e-53ce-4ab8-8de8-3894086bd694
content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_7d6bec6f-eced-4cd9-8b40-9f9c528fd987
Connection: Keep-Alive
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx

--changeset_7d6bec6f-eced-4cd9-8b40-9f9c528fd987      
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
DataServiceVersion: 3.0

POST https://stg1235.table.core.windows.net/Tahsel HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata        
Accept-Encoding: identity
x-ms-date: 2021-12-06 22:12:15.862319Z
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
x-ms-version: 2020-10-02
content-type: application/json
content-length: 259
If-Match: *

{"PartitionKey":"info","RowKey":"session_e1a63e98-76f5-40e5-a529-bf065c025201","accId":"a9ee53f4-b61a-4bfa-a02a-378d45ce1996","accTitle":"147","amount":null,"userId":null,"userTitle":null,"pwd":null,"isAdmin":null,"accounts":null,"note":null,"TimeStamp":null}

--changeset_7d6bec6f-eced-4cd9-8b40-9f9c528fd987      
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
DataServiceVersion: 3.0

POST https://stg1235.table.core.windows.net/Tahsel HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata        
Accept-Encoding: identity
x-ms-date: 2021-12-06 22:12:15.862319Z
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
x-ms-version: 2020-10-02
content-type: application/json
content-length: 259
If-Match: *

{"PartitionKey":"info","RowKey":"session_a9ee53f4-b61a-4bfa-a02a-378d45ce1996","accId":"a9ee53f4-b61a-4bfa-a02a-378d45ce1996","accTitle":"147","amount":null,"userId":null,"userTitle":null,"pwd":null,"isAdmin":null,"accounts":null,"note":null,"TimeStamp":null}

--changeset_7d6bec6f-eced-4cd9-8b40-9f9c528fd987      
--batch_8360b73e-53ce-4ab8-8de8-3894086bd694
''';
```

response body is like this:

```
--batchresponse_653e0e1c-9c26-4ae4-b719-73ac6941ea35  
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_88428c7e-a6c1-42b2-88d4-3e5302598b3e

--changesetresponse_88428c7e-a6c1-42b2-88d4-3e5302598b3e
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>InvalidInput</code><message xml:lang="en-US">0:An error occurred while processing this request.
RequestId:423d29a2-f002-0060-6dee-eab0ca000000        
Time:2021-12-06T22:12:19.5460529Z</message></error>   
--changesetresponse_88428c7e-a6c1-42b2-88d4-3e5302598b3e--
--batchresponse_653e0e1c-9c26-4ae4-b719-73ac6941ea35--
```

I also tried `http.MultipartRequest` to send the payload as fields once and as files an other time, and all failed

I use `http.Request` to send and receive data successfully with all CRUD operations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'--changeset_7d6bec6f-eced-4cd9-8b40-9f9c528fd987--'
```

the closing change set must have a closing `--`